# Discriminating between different PHP exceptions

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I have some IF/THEN logic that is getting difficult to read, and am thinking of using using exceptions instead.

The code will test the user input, and throw exceptions as appropriate.  My catch statement will deal with the anticipated exceptions, but if the exception is not anticipated (like I messed up a PDO statement), I wish to throw the exception and let PHP's error system deal with it.  All of the anticipated exceptions are pretty much dealt with the same way, and I don't wish to use multiple try/catches around each test.

Within the catch statement, how can I perform different actions based on the exception?

```
try {
    $user_input=$_POST['user_input'];
    // rest of code here...
    if (test1($user_input)) {
        throw new Exception("Anticipated exception 1."); 
    }
    // rest of code here...
    //Some PDO which might generate a non-anticipated exception
    if (test2($user_input)) {
        throw new Exception("Anticipated exception 2."); 
    }
    // rest of code here...
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    if(anticipatedException($e)) {
        //Deal with it
    }
    else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you group your particular exceptions to have a common ancestor?

Comment: @mario  I don't understand.  Please elaborate.

Comment: Such as `UserInputTooShortExc extends CommonInputExceptions` and `UserInputTooLong` etc. doing the same; then just catching the `Common..Exc` instead.

Comment: "All of the anticipated exceptions are pretty much dealt with the same way" vs "how can I perform different actions based on the exception". Pick one.

Comment: @mario  Ah, maybe.  I've never done so, but will read the manual.  Thanks

Comment: @iainn. I wish to differentiate between the two I threw and any other exception.  I don't need to differentiate between the two I threw as they can be treated the same.

Comment: *"I wish to throw the exception and let PHP's error system deal with it"* - please note that PHP [errors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.basics.php) and [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) are two different things and they have different behaviour and handling mode.

Comment: @axiac  Meaning, I will let PHP throw an uncatched exception error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using different exceptions. i.e.

```
class ExceptionOne extends Exception {}
class ExceptionTwo extends Exception {}

try {
    $user_input=$_POST['user_input'];
    // rest of code here...
    if (test1($user_input)) {
        throw new ExceptionOne("Anticipated exception 1."); 
    }
    // rest of code here...
    //Some PDO which might generate a non-anticipated exception  
    if (test2($user_input)) {
        throw new ExceptionTwo("Anticipated exception 2."); 
    }
    // rest of code here...
}
catch (ExceptionOne $e) {
    /*...*/
}
catch (ExceptionTwo $e) {
    /*...*/
}
```

Also check Predefined exceptions which might help to group yours: http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php

Comment: Thanks johannes.  Where would the PDO exception be caught?  Could I just put `catch (Exception $e) {throw $e;}` at the end?

Comment: PDO throws an `PDOException`, so you `catch (PDOException $e)` http://php.net/pdoexception

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  Wasn't thinking.  If a PDO exception occurred, it wouldn't be caught, so why catch it and throw it again.  Thanks, got it!

Comment: @user1032531 There's really no point to catch an error just to re-throw it if you're not doing anything within the catch.  Ha, I see you realized this yourself 4 seconds before my comment  :)

Comment: It can be good to catch exceptions like from PDO and wrap them in a custom type. i.e. `catch(PDOExcpetion $e) { throw new MyModuleException("failed to receive data", 0, $e); }` then other code can catch `MyModuleException` even if you replace the database. When doing this mind to pass the original exception along (3rd arg to Exception's constructor) so you can find the origin when debugging http://php.net/exception.getprevious